# Is there a way to write a script to send a message based on how long you’ve watched a Youtube video?

Tags: python, youtube

say you need to watch a lecture on youtube - you run this script and every ten mins you get a reaffirming message to keep going or something, ideally for motivation. is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is possible. You can write a Chrome extension that uses Javascript with a timer function.

You can use Javascript function setInterval to call a handler every ten minutes, for example:

```
setInterval(displayMessage, 10 * 60 * 1000);
```

To start you could try create alerts, such as:

```
alert("Keep going!")
```

And then for more complexity later on you could create toast pop up messages on the page